# How to achive $('button').click(function() in angular 6

Tags: angular

I want write a click event on button , like we use to do before in jquery.
e.g. - 
`$('button').click(function(){ 
      // do some stuff 
 });`

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
 <button class="fa fa-btc" >Click</button>
 <button class="fa fa-btc" >Click</button>
 <button class="fa fa-btc" >Click</button>
 <button class="fa fa-btc" >Click</button>
 <button class="fa fa-btc" >Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean the basics of Angular ? Do you know [there is a very thorough documentation](https://angular.io/docs) that you can read to learn how to use Angular ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this in angular

```
in component.html

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6" *ngFor="let item of items">
 <button class="fa fa-btc" (click)="myFunction()">{{item.name}}</button>
```

```
 in component.ts

  myFunction(){
       // do something
   }
```

Comment: I don't want to call function from html, i want to click  html button element from ts

Comment: do you want to call your function on component load?

Comment: I have 100 hard coded buttons on my html page , i want call a single function from any one of them get clicked, and function not to be called from html click

Answer (score 0):

it's simple

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6" *ngFor="let item of items">
 <button class="fa fa-btc" (click)="btnClick();">{{item.name}}
  </button>
</div>
```

and it ts decalere that function

```
btnClick(){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the click event to the button as follows

```
<button class="fa fa-btc" (click)="executeFunc()" >{{item.name}}</button>
```

and in TS

```
executeFunc(){
}
```